# Rails 3: Find_or_create_by_name not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm trying to do a `find_or_create_by` function in my locations model. The attributes are saving but the *find or create* function isn't working. I have a `name` field and if I enter `'London'`, it is saving despite this value already being in the table.

Any suggestions why this may be?

EDIT: Added before_save invocation, as suggested by comment. - Still having the same problem.

*Locations.rb*

```
  class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
     before_save :location_check
     has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
     has_many :assets
     attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :name, :post_id, :notes, :asset, :assets_attributes
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
     include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers


   def location_check
    def locations_attributes=(values)
    self.location = Location.find_or_create_by_name(values)
   end
 end  
end
```

EDIT: Here is the output log:

```
INSERT INTO "locations" ("created_at", "latitude", "longitude", "name", "notes", "post_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
 ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:48:50 UTC +00:00], ["latitude", nil],    ["longitude", nil], ["name", "London"], ["notes", "notes"], ["p
 ost_id", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:48:50 UTC +00:00]]
```

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for your comment. I wasn't sure whether invokation was necessary. I've amended this but there's no change. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `Location.find_or_create_by_name(name: values)`

Comment: Thanks Kien but this change makes no difference. The entry simply saves without checking. Any other suggestions? 

`def location_check
  def locations_attributes=(values)
    self.location = Location.find_or_create_by_name(name: values)
  end
end  `

Comment: hmm, maybe you should change it to `first_or_create`: `Location.where(name: values).first_or_create`

Comment: I guess I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, but find_or_create_by_name doesn't take a hash.  It takes a single string containing the name to look up or create with...

Comment: Thanks Kien but it's still saving without checking first, any other ideas? @Philip, this may be where i'm going wrong. I'm passing variables such as ':name,:longitude,:latitude'and ':notes' through as 'values'. I only want to check the name is 'found_or_unique'. Is there a way I can do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I'd refactor it like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
   has_many :assets
   attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :name, :post_id, :notes, :asset, :assets_attributes
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

   validates :name, :uniqueness => true
```

end

Then in your controllers do:

```
loc = Location.find_or_create_by_name('London')
```

And if you forget and try to do:

```
loc = Location.create(:name => 'London')
```

and that record already exists, it will fail the uniqueness validation.

Comment: Hi @Philip! Thanks for this answer! This works great in my 'Locations' controller, however, I was testing in the 'Locations' model because I need to apply it in my 'Posts' through a nested form.

I figured the model would be the best way to do this. I'm unsure how to apply the 'find_or_create' when passing variables through something like `@post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])` 

I appreciate all the help so far, any other ideas for this final bit?

Comment: That I don't know... you'd need to dig into nested_attributes to see what's available.

Answer (score 0):

could it be due to the case difference between what you had and the input entered? E.g: London and london

Comment: Hi @lifejuggler, Yep it's defo not down to typo's (tried a few different names).